# Google Event With jQuery Form Submit Listener

Tags: jquery, forms, cross-browser, google-analytics

I am using a simple jQuery to recognize when a form is submitted on my site and log a goal with Google Universal Analytics, as follows:

```
     $('form').submit( function(event) {
    var form = this;

    event.preventDefault();

    ga('send', 'event', 'Test', 'Test', 'Test');

    setTimeout( function () { 
        form.submit();
    }, 300);
});
```

On some of our forms, this works.

```
<form method="post" name="FormName" action="myURL" id="formID">
<input type="image" src="http://mySource" value="Submit" style="font-size: 100%; height: 47px; width: 251px">
```

On some of our forms, the goal is fired but you are not taken to the confirmation message.

```
<form name="myForm" method="post" action="myURL" onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();" id="myForm">
 <input type="submit" name="myName" value="Submit >>" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;bodycontent_0$centerpane_1$EloquaSubmit&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="myID" />
```

On some of our forms, the goal is not fired, but you are taken to the confirmation message.

```
<form name="myName" onsubmit="return isReady(this)" action="myURL" method="post">
<input type="image" src="myURL" alt="Register Now!">
```

Any ideas on how I could make this bit of code work for all of my forms?

Comment: jQuery event handlers should be cross browser, so you're probably doing something else wrong ?

Comment: Are you using a http analyzer (Firebug > Net (tab)) or HTTPFox (Firefox Plugin) to monitor the request getting sent to GA? If so, is there a request being sent?

Comment: @Blexy thanks for the tip, got Firebug and I think it was a time delay issue. I updated the script to account for this, but now other issues are appearing.